# Not able to get list of arrays

Tags: php

I'm receiving data from my remote database, I'm stuck on how to print all arrays in one list.

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    getCountryInfo();
}

function getCountryInfo()
{
    global $conn;
    $values_array = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `countryInfo`ORDER BY `countryID`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $values_array[] = $row['countryName'];
        $values_array[] = $row['countryPhone'];
        $values_array[] = $row['countryCurrency'];

        // i'm getting each 3 values in one array , now i want to add each array to a list
        // so that i finally get list of arrays
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: @PaulT. I'm getting all values , no issue with values , since i need to get data into my android app , i want to echo data from php as list of data ( or list of array ) , because each row has 3 values , want each 3 values in on array , and then add those array to list and echo it for my android app , hope you got my point , Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$values_array[] = [
    'countryName'=> $row['countryName'],
    'countryPhone'=> $row['countryPhone'],
    'countryCurrency'=> $row['countryCurrency']
];
```